# how to capture the image on website and show them on other web page

Tags: java, html

my problem is that i want to read html data and image of some other web site and show them in my web page .i have used following code snippet

```
URL iurl=new URL("https://abc.com");
URLConnection uRLConnection=iurl.openConnection();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uRLConnection.getInputStream()));
String line;
int i=0;
PrintWriter pw=response.getOutputStream();
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
{
pw.write(line)
}
```

or

```
InputStream is= urlconnection.getInputStream();  

  outputStream.close();


OutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
    int data;
 byte[] dataByte=new byte[1024];
 while((data=is.read(dataByte))!=-1)
 {
     out.write(dataByte);
 }
```

but both are not able to generate mirror copy of web page so how i can generate the same.
please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying to retrieve using `URLConection` only retrieves the source of that page.

So if the `CSS` for the same page is stored in another file, it wont be retrieved. Only the `HTML` part will be taken and displayed.

Thus to create an exact mirror image of the page, you will have to read the `url of the CSS` file too and store it separately with the html code.

Comment: thanks for help but in case of image how it could be possible because when i render the image only one image get rendered on whole page

Comment: i even use this  IIOImage first_IIOImage = new IIOImage(img1, null, null);
    Iterator writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)writers.next();
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
writer.setOutput(ios);
if(i==0)
    writer.write(null, first_IIOImage, null);
else if(writer.canInsertImage(i))
  writer.writeInsert(i,first_IIOImage , null);  but writer.canInsertImage(i) retuen false can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: could be more than one reasons. you may wanna try some libraries that allow displaying webpage in java applications like this http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/

Comment: but will it work for web page because i want to show the output on web page

Comment: yes it will. the information is given on the link i provided.

Comment: anurag i think it output only for swing which run on desktop but i need to show web page on web browser

Answer (score 0):

Use JEditorPane (read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)). All you practically need is:

```
JEditorPane jep;
jep.setPage(url); //url is a String
```

Comment: If you provide a valid URL to JEditorPane it will display the whole webpage almost like an Internet browser.

Comment: Do you want to download the images or serve them as links to the original web page?

Comment: Ok, you can download the image and show it but you can also display that via a link to its original location. Is that an option?

Comment: via a link to its original location. Is not an option because on each call this image get changed(capthca image)

Comment: You could also take a look at ImageIO class. You could use read(URL input) to get BufferedImage

Comment: image io is able to read but on writing it is showing only a single image on whole web page